# Different outputs, same code Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

This is my code:

```
public boolean isValidAccount(Account a) {
    boolean valid = false;
    EntityTransaction tx = AbstractService.getEntityTransaction();
    try {
        tx.begin();
        if (AbstractService.getEntityManager().createQuery("from Account a where a.naam = :naam")
                .setParameter("naam", a.getNaam()).getSingleResult() != null) {
            valid = true;
            return valid;
        }
        tx.commit();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        tx.rollback();
    }
    return valid;
}
```

and when i do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AccountService as = new AccountService();
    Account testAccount = new Account();
    testAccount.setNaam("a");
    testAccount.setWachtwoord("a");
    boolean yes = as.isValidAccount(testAccount);
    System.out.println(yes);
    boolean yes2 = as.isValidAccount(testAccount);
    System.out.println(yes2);
    boolean yes3 = as.isValidAccount(testAccount);
    System.out.println(yes3);
}
```

The output is :

```
true
false
true
```

Assuming that my database consists of an account with name: a and password a

How could this happen?

Comment: Your `return valid` in `try` will break transaction, remove it and try again, this may work.

Comment: Note that you can rewrite `valid = true; return valid;` just by `return true;`. In the same way you can replace `return valid;` at the end of the method with `return false;`.

Comment: You can try to print something in the `catch` block, so you know if the catch block is reached or not.

Comment: @kimixuchen Thank you, that was the solution! i removed return valid;

Comment: But why do you need a transaction for read operation ?

Comment: Actually i don't know @javaguy